# How to connect/read/write to Firebase in VB.Net using REST?

Tags: vb.net, rest, firebase

I am trying to develop a windows app that connects to Firebase, but I can't find any sources on how to do this, I am assuming that there is no Firebase object that I can use in .Net platform.

Can you please show me a basic code lines for how to do:

1 - User create and Auth operations

2 - Reading single and array/list value(s)  operations

3 - Writing single and array/list value(s)  operations

Thank you in advance

Comment: [FireSharp](https://github.com/ziyasal/FireSharp) is a .NET library for accessing Firebase. Though written in C#, it can be used from VB.NET as well. The alternative would be to access the [Firebase REST API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/) directly from your VB code, which mimics what FireSharp (and many other third-party libraries for accessing Firebase) do.

Comment: Is there any examples or VBNet codes of Firebase REST API?